# PHP calculation with two variables

Tags: php

I am trying to generate a new variable using two previous variables in a sum:

```
$newseats = $origseats - $requiredseats;
$newskis = $origskis - $skis;
```

However, this is not working and I am not sure what to do about it. If I replace either of the variables in the sum with a number e.g:

```
$newseats = $origseats - 1;
```

it will work.

Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: Please do `var_dump($variable);` with every variable and tell us what the output is, so we see which input you use. Also specify `not working`, do you get any errors? Is the result 42 or what?

Comment: I highly suggest figuring out what `$requiredseats`, `$skis` etc. actually is, using something like [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) or [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: @Rizier123 by not working I mean that the new variable e.g $newseats is blank, if it try to print the variable, nothing will appear.

Comment: @DJDavid98 is there any way of getting around this?

Comment: Why would you want to "get around" basic debugging.  You need to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the variables might be strings. If you add/substract a number from/to a string, it is converted, but if you do it on 2 strings it's not.

To get around this, convert the values using `intval` to get an integer "number" type result that you can work with. It's probably better to do it when you're setting these variables the first time, though.

```
$newseats = intval($origseats) - intval($requiredseats);
$newskis = intval($origskis) - intval($skis);
```

Comment: it also works for strings. try `echo "101" - "98";` However `intval()` does not hurt.